# Find representative observation by mean for each class in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an dataset with multiclass and I want to get representative row for each class. For instance,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5],
              'B':['Apple','Orange','Apple','Banana','Kiwi','Apple','Orange','Apple','Banana','Kiwi'],
              'C':['Boy','Boy','Boy','Girl','Girl','Boy','Boy','Boy','Girl','Girl'],
              'D':[1000,2000,1000,3000,3000,1000,2000,1000,3000,3000],
              'Target':['X','X','Y','Z','X','X','X','Y','Z','X']
              })
```

[image]

What I need is to find agent row by using Target feature.

I've used this way but it isn't what I want.

```
df.groupby('Target').mean()
```

Should I convert categorical columns to numeric and then get the mean? What I am concerning is after getting mean how can I be sure which categorical variable should it be belonging? Say, I get a float value for `B` column which fruit should it belong? Should I just round? At the and wanna have

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
df['B'] = le.fit_transform(df['B'])
df['C'] = le.fit_transform(df['C'])
```

The result for `df.groupby('Target').mean()` is

[image]

But how can I get representative observation just like in the dataframe?

Comment: If you want to round or not and/or how to preprocess categorical variables strongly depends on your problem formulation. Just think about it, if there can be a mean of a banana and an orange *at all*. Does it make sense?

Comment: It won't a big deal actually. All I want is kind of sample from each class

Comment: Yeah, but what will be the meaning of `Kiwi + Apple + Orange = 3 + 1 + 2 = 6` (assuming Kiwi=3, Apple = 1, Orange=2) with the mean of the group being `6/3=2==Orange`? If you want to compare prices f.i., you'd have to make sure that the cat. encoding is scaling with the price, or more explicitly: that the replacement for the string is the price.

Comment: My intention is to get 3 observations for each (X,Y,Z) class. This is just a sample case for me. My actual dataset doesn't have same scenario. It makes sense in that dataset.

Comment: Yep, then rounding after encoding may be a solution. But without knowing the exact use case, it is even harder to tell if rounding is fine in the scope of your problem formulation.

Comment: Is there a way to decode after getting mean values for desired samples? I mean to see again with a categorical values. I guess it depends on the way I use for encoding, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221808/discussion-between-quilliam-and-scotty1).